# Change figure/equation labels, along with their \ref?

Tags: cross-referencing

Say I labeled a Equation with `\label{ABC}`, and refer to it couple of times with `\ref{ABC}`. Now I want to change the label to `\label{XYZ}`. Is there an automatic way that those `\ref{ABC}` will be simultaneously changed to `\ref{XYZ}`?

I also have multiple `.tex` files and `\input` them to the main file. So search/replace doesn't work well...

Comment: this would be a good reason to learn about [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the references equivalent. Consider the following setup:

```
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \label{abc}
\end{equation}
See~(\ref{abc}).
```

Now you change the label to `\label{xyz}`. In order to make all `abc` labels still reference the newly defined `xyz`, you can execute

```
\makeatletter
\let\r@abc\r@xyz
\makeatother
```

Here's a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \label{xyz}% ...was \label{abc}
\end{equation}
\makeatletter
\let\r@abc\r@xyz% Reference abc is equivalent to xyz
\makeatother
See~(\ref{abc}) and~(\ref{xyz}).
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is helpful to know this fact. However, it does not directly solve my problem...

Comment: @YuHu: Does the updated answer seem more promising?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @cmhughes's comment, use sed:

```
sed -i 's/\\ref{ABC}/\\ref{XYZ}/g' *.tex
```